# source.<library> configuration is not considered

Tags: plugins, eclipse-rcp, manifest, rcp

I have created a new plugin in my RCP application. I am building this as eclipse-plugin using maven. I have added the following Plug-in specific property in build.properties.

```
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               OSGI-INF/,\
               resources/
javacProjectSettings = true
javacDefaultEncoding.. = UTF-8
jars.compile.order = .
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
```

But the sources are not compiled and not include in the generated plugin. Because of this, I am getting class not found exception in RCP. In other plugins also using source.. = src/ property where the sources are compiled and included in generated plugin successfully.
I am not sure what I have missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `bin.includes` is missing `.` for the default output directory:

```
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               OSGI-INF/,\
               .,\
               resources/
```